# Elasticsearch: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors (ca.crt matches on all nodes)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

Note that this entire cluster was working fine up 'til I updated certificates. I'm on Elasticsearch 7.5.

I updated my certificates using the certificate-util - created a server.yml with all my servers and the Kibana node in it, ran the utility with -pem, -multiple, and --keep-ca-key, passed the ca.crt and the various node certificates out to the nodes, made sure the elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml files pointed to them as appropriate, and did a rolling restart. And then everything fell apart.

The main issue - the one I'm currently having at least - is that I'm getting the error in the topic. In full, a log from an Elastic node it's talking to:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:473) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:600) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:554) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) [netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkClientCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1275) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1178) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1159) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1502) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1516) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1400) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:349) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:258) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkClientTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkClientCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1253) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1178) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1159) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1502) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1516) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1400) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:158) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:344) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:258) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkClientTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkClientCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1253) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1178) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1159) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1502) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1516) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1400) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        ... 16 more
```

All of my nodes are giving a similar error.

On the surface, it looks fairly straightforward - you'd think the ca.crt is wrong on the Kibana node (at least, that's what I found from searching.) If it's wrong though, I don't know why - it's literally the same ca.crt as I've got on all the other nodes.

As far as I can tell, I don't have a keystore explicitly configured, and the output from elasticsearch-keystore looks like the following:

```
[root@Kibana Node kibana]# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
bootstrap.password
keystore.seed
xpack.security.authc.realms.active_directory.platform_ad.secure_bind_password
```

If Java's got a keystore, I can't locate that either, at least with the name "keystore" - if someone knows where that might be configured, it'd probably be a good next step.

I'm not sure what else I could do to troubleshoot - my Google-fu is failing me (and everything I found pointed at the CA indeed being the problem, in the simplest manner - they mismatched. If they're mismatched in this case, it's the fault of the certificate utility, but comparing them with openssl doesn't see any differences.)

Quick summary:
The same ca.crt used to generate all certificates for a cluster doesn't seem to be trusted on Kibana, but appears to work on other nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this turned out to be a sneaky and two-fold issue.

The first issue is that I typoed the path I used on *one* of the ca.crt entries in my configuration - think "cert" vs. "certs" which made it not find the certificate (not that it actually *told* me that anywhere in the logging...) It's likely that this was masking the second issue.

The second issue seemed to be that Elastic didn't like me changing the path used from the default of $ES_HOME$/certs/.crt and $ES_HOME$/certs/ca/ca.crt. Someone I was troubleshooting with noticed a little quip in a certificate setup document that basically said "Elasticsearch will sometimes have issues finding a certificate if you change the path that it's pointing to, no matter whether you have the permissions set up correctly or not." Again, not like it *told* me this anywhere in the logs...

It's incredibly dumb, but changing the path back to the default and moving the certificates back to the original folders made it pick up the certificates as expected and communicate after the first typo fix didn't work.